# I am tryng to dual-boot Ubuntu 11.10 and Fedora 16

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, fedora

I am going to dual-boot Ubuntu 11.10 and Fedora 16. I am installing Ubuntu first. Partitioning 15 MB for Boot partition, and the rest of my space divided by 2 for each Ubuntu and Fedora (500 GB each). I set the Fedora partition not to be used by Ubuntu. I am not using Swap partition. After the installation, do I have to manually configure grub? Or will the Fedora installer do the job for me?

Comment: strictly speaking - you are asking what fedora will do which is off-topic for this forum.  If you ask the question the other way around then it will be a on-topic.  However saying that, fedora 16 uses grub 2 - so I strongly suspect, it will automatically detect ubuntu in the same way as ubuntu auo-detects other windows and ubuntu installations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would install Fedora first because its installation is much more difficult than Ubuntu's installation. Ubuntu will also set everything for you. You do not need to create a separate partition as a boot partition. Just install fedora and when you install Ubuntu choose the "install alongside fedora (or other linux distribution)" and Ubuntu will do the rest.

Comment: Here is what I did. I started the Fedora Installer, Made a 100 MB partition (thanks @enedene) for the bootloader, and 2 500GB partitions for each of 2 operating systems, installed Fedora on 1 of them, after the installation of Fedora, I ran the Ubuntu Installer and installed it on the other 500GB partition. After restarting my PC i got Grub bootloader with both operating systems in it. And what is the best, in each OS I can mount the other's 500GB partition. Basically I got what I wanted. Thanks for help Everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which linux you install first.

The one you install second will be the grub that is actually used. Whenever update-grub is ran, grub will be reinstalled.

In ubuntu this is done whenever there is a kernel upgrade and fedora is likely the same.

Therefore, by default, you'll be switching back and forth between grub installs as each distro is updated (assuming you using each quite often)

As both use autoconfiguration, it's not big of a deal and will only be a minor annoyance.

Please see my question to see my conclusions on this topic.
[How to dual boot two different Linux distributions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54204/how-to-dual-boot-two-different-linux-distributions)

Answer (score 1):

15MB for a boot partition? Make that 100MB.
Installer will install grub, except if you deny it. Just watch out for partitioning, automatic could overwrite the previous installation. I haven't installed Fedora in a while, but I think you'll be prompted a choice, or you can do it manually, that shouldn't be hard.